# Ethereal Vision/Spell casting confusion. Need as written, not opinions

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, vision-and-light, ethereal-plane

**Need "As Written", as there are many "opinions" out there.

Ethereal confusion: A Night Hag, while in the ethereal plane, sees and touches someone in the material plane with the "Nightmare" (Magical) ability. Does that mean the hag can cast spells like counterspell in the same way?

The hag can both see and interact with things in the material plane while in the ethereal plane. The "nightmare" ability is magical.

Spells like "Counterspell" are vision-based.

And yes I saw the fake JeremyECrawford's tweet about planes being infinite distance away, but that account has been removed and all the tweets from that account are considered tainted, biased, and in my opinion, null and void. It was not actually Jeremy Crawford who posted it.

Comment: For those saying this is a duplicate, how do we explain the fact that the Hag, from the ethereal plane, can actually touch a target on the material plane?

Comment: Related: "[Must a night hag be within touching distance of a sleeping humanoid to use Nightmare Haunting?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/184432)"

Comment: @SeriousBri The general rule is "While on the Ethereal Plane, you can only affect and be affected by other creatures on that plane.", if the Night Hag were meant to bypass that entirely, and not exclusively with one feature, their stat block would say so.

Comment: Is there some kind of conspiracy theory going around that Crawford's twitter account (which still exists and very much hasn't been removed) isn't actually him?

Comment: @Carcer You’d probably get downvoted to hell and have your question closed, but I would upvote you so hard if you posted that as a main site question.

Comment: @Exempt-Medic the feature says nothing about bypassing the general rule, it simply says they have to touch. We decide that bypasses the general rule in the linked questions, but maybe they just can because they are special, or maybe the general rule is interpreted wrong. Either way I think that needs exploring in an answer and not ignoring while we direct people to questions which can't and won't talk about that aspect. If the Hag can touch someone it HAS to be within 60ft of them somehow.

Comment: However I didn't realise my reopen vote would actually reopen it. It didn't do that on a question yesterday!

Comment: @SeriousBri This isn’t the first time you’ve said you didn’t know you could unilaterally reopen a question, the rules for gold badges and dupe closures can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/674198).

Comment: @ThomasMarkov thank you for that, I did know that after the last time I asked (kind of) which is why I am reluctant to vote these days, but yesterday one didn't reopen which confused me. I will see if I can spot it and see what the difference was.

Comment: For the Matter, Crawford tweets haven't been official rulling for years by now....

Comment: I mean, tweets have NEVER been official rulings, they're just occasionally useful insight into one of the lead dev's thoughts, but that still doesn't explain why the OP thinks he's fake.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym earlier versions of the Sage Advice Compendium did actually say "[...] the game’s rules manager, Jeremy Crawford (@JeremyECrawford), can make official rulings and usually does so in Sage Advice *and on Twitter.*" It was accepted that Jeremy's tweets sometimes constituted official rulings at that time. (Of course they later realised that errata-by-twitter wasn't a good idea.)